# PHP: Отправка нескольких файлов в JSON

Tags: php

Добрый день
Сразу прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, абсолютный новичок в php.
На форме есть поле для прикрепления нескольких фото:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <p><input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple accept="image/*,image/jpeg"></p>
</form>
```

После выбора и нажатия на спец кнопку они вместе с другими полями должны отправиться на один сервис POST-запросом в формате JSON. Вот есть такой код формирования тела запроса:

```
$data = array(
  "ordernumber" => $_POST['ordernumber'],
  "orderdate" => $_POST['orderdate']
);
$postData = json_encode($data);
```

Вопрос: как добавить сюда массив прикрепленных файлов с именами и двоичными данными?

Comment: Если отправить  надо в виде json, то у знайте в каком виде ожидает данные сервис. Данные надо закодировать в строку, но каким именно образом, скажет только спецификация/документация принимающей стороны. вероятно, конечно, что это будет base64, но не факт.

Comment: Принимающий сервис делаю тоже я. :-) Да, base64 подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Может для начала картинки нужно загрузить на сервер? И потом передать путь картинки... А так как Вы хотите не получится... Вы сможете передать только имя изображения и все, а саму картинку нет... Загрузите изображения, потом получите полный урл на них и передавайте в json...

Comment: Мне кажется должен быть другой способ. Вот, например в Google Drive REST API есть загрузка файла через отправку данных: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert
Хотел что-то подобное сделать.